# What's the superclass of class Object in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, keyword

I just wonder what is the the superclass of class Object in Java?

Comment: I wonder how much effort you've invested to answer the question by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no super class for Object, try this

```
    System.out.println(Object.class.getSuperclass());
```

it prints null

Answer (score 6):

`java.lang.Object` doesn't have super class, and [this is **not** an implementation of `clone()` method of `java.lang.Object`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Object.java#Object.clone%28%29), You are looking at [`ArrayList#clone()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.clone%28%29)

Answer (score 4):

> I just wonder what is the the superclass of class Object in Java?

[There is none.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)

> The class `Object` is a superclass (§8.1.4) of all other classes.

Answer (score 1):

There is **No Super class** of `Object class`. [Check out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)